# How to diff only the contents of two directories, not the files themselves

Tags: recursion, diff, directory

This will seem like one of those "been asked a hundred times" questions, but it is nuanced:

I have two directories and I only want to compare their file structure (whether files & directories are missing or not).  I don't care about any differences in the content of the files themselves.

This is important for two reasons.  First, I know that many files in one directory will be different from the other, but I don't care about that, I only care if some files/directories are present or missing.  Secondly, the two directories are enormous (many many GB) and I don't want diff to have to compare the contents, which will take forever.

Is diff even the right tool for this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems straightforward to diff the file listing:

```
find dir1 | sort | sed 's/^dir1//' > dir1-list
find dir2 | sort | sed 's/^dir2//' | diff - dir1-list
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to work on condensing it a bit, but this is a great approach.